# Numerical analysis algorithm implemetation results in infinite loop

Tags: python, numerical-analysis

I've been trying to implement the following numerical analysis function for an exercise: *create a python script that finds the minimum value of "n" required to reach machine accuracy for the result*

[image]

[image]

Firstly, I wrote the following code assuming machine accuracy is 1e-15 (the given y(x) is defined in the fun(x) function.)

```
import math
import numpy as np

def fun(x):
    return float(x**4*(math.sqrt(x**2 + 9)))

i = 1
n_start = 2
n = n_start
y = 0.0
while True:
    if i == n:
        term_val = (math.pi/n)*y
        if n != n_start:
            print("term", term_val)
            print(abs(term_val - term_val_past))
            if abs(term_val - term_val_past) < 1e-15:
                print("Reached machine precision for n=", n)
                break
        y = 0.0
        n += 1
        i = 1
        term_val_past = term_val
    x_i =  math.cos((math.pi/(2*n))*(2*i-1))
    y += fun(x_i)
    i += 1
```

This code seems to run forever and doesn't get close to the required accuracy, however it reaches 4 decimal accuracy after a while (expected result is about 3.69412640477 and n = 12).

Not being able to find the problem with my solution I rewrote part of the script and it seems to work fine now (reached required accuracy for n = 12)

```
import math
import numpy as np

def fun(x):
    return float(x**4*(math.sqrt(x**2 + 9)))

i = 1
n_start = 1
n = n_start
y = 0.0
while True:
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        x_i = math.cos(math.pi/(2*n)*(2*i-1))
        y += fun(x_i)
    term_val = (math.pi/n)*y
    if n != n_start:
        if abs(term_val - term_val_past) < 1e-15:
            print("Reached machine precision for n=", n)
            print("Result:", term_val)
            break
    y = 0.0
    n += 1
    term_val_past = term_val
```

I would really like to know where I made the mistake in my first solution, it really boggles my mind.

Thanks in advance.